# keyboard splitting hangs in opengl app

Tags: opengl-es, ios5, freeze

I have OpenGL application with UITextField in the main menu. When I tap on the text field the keyboard appears and I can edit the text. But if I running under iOS 5 and if I try to split keyboard then the keyboard starts splitting (I mean animation) and then hangs when I release my fingers. I mean it hangs on half splitting - and does not responds more. But my app is still alive - and render is working well - background animation is still working.

I have just made a simple test - have disabled the render at all. And the problem has gone. So the problem is related to OpenGL.

I use OpenGL ES 1.1, 
XCode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0.

Do somebody have similar problems? Any suggestions?

Please help.

---

UPDATE:
I have just tested two more games from AppStore - and in one I have found this problem too!
'Roads of Rome HD free' - iPad game.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this problem too, but I was able to fix it due to previous experiences. In one application we found that if we keep our GL view active while playing video, the video playback position slider didn't behave smoothly. The same seems to happen with the keyboard split. If your problem is the same as mine, the issue is related to the keyboard split animation not finishing (and, in our case, the point where remained struck varied with each test)

We solved the issue stopping the animation on your GL view (I bet it's called EAGLView) when receiving a `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` notification and starting it again after `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I just came across this problem in ios 8 on an iPad3.

Running an OpenGL app at 60fps seems to throttle the keyboard update. Reducing your FPS while the keyboard overlay is active will fix the issue.

I'm using GLKViewController to manage the update and Draw callbacks with a 60fps refresh, but that was causing the keyboard split to lock up half completed.
I found the best solution for me was to set the view's preferredFramesPerSecond to 20 while receiving text input,  and then set back to 60 after the textView is closed. As well as fixing the keyboard hang, it also just makes the keyboard generally more responsive.

```
myViewController.preferredFramesPerSecond = 20;
```